# What is the proper way to test if the function F queries for the right data

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

I want to ensure that my following `findOne` functions contain needed relations, joins, wheres and so on.

```js
async findOne(id: string) {
  return this.repo.findOne({
    where: { id },
    relations: [
      'foo',
      'bar',
    ],
  });
}

async findAnotherOne(id: string) {
  const qb = this.repo.createQueryBuilder('foo');
  qb.select('bar.id'),
  qb.where('id = :id', { id });
  qb.leftJoin('foo.bar', 'bar');
  return qb.getOne();
}
```

What would the tests look like? I thought about something like:

```
expect(repo).toHaveRelations(['foo', 'bar']);
// or
expect(repo).toSelect(...).toJoin(...).toWhere(...)...
```

If this is not possible, how can I asure that my function always returns the right data? Mocking a return value with an object containing all needed data can't be the way. This doesn't prevent someone from altering the querybuilder.

Comment: You call it, and see if the result you get back corresponds with the known state of the DB.

Comment: You mean I actual perform the query on the (Test) DB and check if the result contains the needed data? Is there a way to do this with just a unit test?

Comment: Unit testing what you show would make no sense, it's entirely coupled to the persistence domain via a complex API you don't own. Replace the repo with a test double for unit testing its consumers, but test this at an integration level.